# How do I increment a variable when the previous value of another value is two greater than its predecessor?

Tags: sql, sas

Using the image below as reference how do I use SQL or a SAS data step to add the variable in green?

Each time the ordinal_data column increases by 2 the value in the want column should increment.

I've tried working of of this snippet:

```
data want;
set rows_data;
rownum + 1;
by ordinal_rows;
if first.ordinal_rows then rownum =1;
run;
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the LAG() function to retrieve previous value stored when the LAG() function executes. Or the DIF() function to retrieve the difference between the current value and the value stored the previous time the DIF() function executed.

```
data want;
  set have;
  by ordinal_rows;
  if dif(ordinal_data) >= 2 then want+1;
  if first.ordinal_rows then want=1;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `lag()` and a cumulative sum:

```
select t.*,
       sum(case when prev_col1 = col1 - 2 then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by col1 order by col2)  as new_col
from (select t.*,
             lag(col2) over (partition by col1 order by col2) as prev_col1
      from t
     ) t;
```

If you want to run this in SAS using `proc sql`, you will need to use the underlying database in native mode.

Answer (score 0):

```
create table [ORIGINAL DATA] (
    ordinal_rows int,
    ordinal_data int,
    [text] varchar(50)
)

insert [ORIGINAL DATA]
values 
  (1, 10, 'wisconsin')
, (1, 12, 'red')
, (1, 13, 'green')
, (1, 14, 'yellow')
, (1, 15, 'purple')
, (1, 16, 'teal')
, (1, 17, 'orange')
, (1, 18, 'black')
, (1, 19, 'white')
, (1, 20, 'grey')
, (1, 21, 'turquoise')
, (1, 22, 'magenta')
, (1, 23, 'pink')
, (1, 24, 'lime')
, (1, 26, 'coors')
, (1, 28, 'miller')
, (1, 29, 'budweiser')
, (1, 30, 'corona')

select ordinal_rows
, ordinal_data
, text
, sum(want) over (order by ordinal_rows, ordinal_data) + 1 as want

from (
    select ordinal_rows
    , ordinal_data
    , text
    , case
        when ordinal_data - lag(ordinal_data) over (order by ordinal_rows, ordinal_data) = 2 then 1
        else 0
      end as want

    from [ORIGINAL DATA]
) q
```